# Javascript - How to destruct an object and clone a property?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I want to destruct an object and clone a specific property, all in a single line. It's possible?

```
const MyObject = {
  sections: [1, 2],
  otherProp: null
};

const { sections } = MyObject; // Not a copy/clone of the array
const sectionsClone = { ...MyObject.sections }; // Works - But is not a destructuration

// Ideal scenario (I know this syntax has an error)
const { ...sections: myIdealScenario } = MyObject
```

Comment: after `const { sections } = MyObject;`, why would that not be ideal?

Comment: It's called "to de-structure" and "de-structuring"

Comment: If you want to copy the array, just be explicit about it: `const sections = MyObject.sections.slice()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
const MyObject = {
  sections: [1, 2],
  otherProp: null
}

const { sections: [...sections] } = MyObject
```

Comment: That's it! In my example I just include one prop; but, yes, with this solution I can include multiple props in a single line. Brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just trying to clone the array in the object, you don't need to destructure it:

```
const MyObject = {
  sections: [1, 2],
  otherProp: null
};

const myIdealScenario = [...MyObject.sections];
```